# GridView doesn't show anything after JSON parsing the values into its items

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have gridview for a tab in tabLayout. I load the values from mysql database to fill the textviews of gridview. I see that the JSON parsing runs correctly and returns correct JSON result. But nothing shows up in grid view.

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mysampleapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GridAdapterStores extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> storename=new ArrayList<String>();
    private  ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public GridAdapterStores(Context c,ArrayList<String> storename, ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks) {
        context = c;
        this.imagelinks = imagelinks;
        this.storename = storename;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return storename.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View grid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_stores,parent,false);
        }
        else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView textViewStoreName = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
        ImageView imageViewStoreImage = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_image);
        textViewStoreName.setText(storename.get(position));
        Integer x=imagelinks.get(position);
        imageViewStoreImage.setImageResource(x);
        return grid;
    }



}
```

```html
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.mysampleapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class StoresFragment extends Fragment {
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private ArrayList<String> storenamefinal=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> imagelinksfinal=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_layout,null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        

        GridView gridview=(GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_stores);
        getData();

        final GridAdapterStores gridadapter= new GridAdapterStores(getActivity(),storenamefinal,imagelinksfinal);
        gridview.setAdapter(gridadapter);
        
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           /* Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             i.setData(Uri.parse(gridadapter.getItem(position).getImageUrlString()));
        startActivity(i);}});*/
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + cat[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), stores_show.class);
                i.putExtra("storename", storenamefinal.get(position));
                getActivity().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    //public class getData extends AsyncTask<String,>>{

    //}
    private void getData() {
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);
        String url = Config1.DATA_URL;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void showJSON(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config1.JSON_ARRAY);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),result.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int i=result.length();
            Log.i("Result Length",result.toString());
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                storenamefinal.add(null);
                imagelinksfinal.add(null);
            }
            String temp;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                JSONObject Data = result.getJSONObject(j);
                Log.i("Data",Data.toString());
                temp= (Data.getString(Config1.KEY_PRIO));
                Log.i("temp", temp.toString());
                storenamefinal.set(Integer.parseInt(temp) - 1, Data.getString(Config1.KEY_NAME));

                Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
                imagelinksfinal.add(R.drawable.sg1);

            }
            Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),storenamefinal.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

}
```

I have tried searching on Google and stackoverflow , found nothing successful,

{"result":[{"storename":"Flipkart.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"2"},{"storename":"Jabong.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"4"},{"storename":"Myntra.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"5"},{"storename":"Amazon.in","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"1"},{"storename":"Snapdeal.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"3"},{"storename":"Koovs.in","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"6"},{"storename":"Limeroad.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"7"},{"storename":"Shopperstop.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"8"},{"storename":"Stalkbuylove.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"9"},{"storename":"Yepme.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"10"},{"storename":"Faballey.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"11"},{"storename":"Fabindia.com ","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"12"},{"storename":"PrettySecrets.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"13"},{"storename":"AmericanSwan.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"14"},{"storename":"Clovia.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"15"},{"storename":"Bata.in","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"16"},{"storename":"TrendyBharat.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"17"},{"storename":"Royzez.com","imagelinks":"","mainpriority":"18"}]}
`

Storenamefinal will have entries of storenames from resulting JSON(above)

Comment: can you share storenamefinal value ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question to include JSON and storenamefinal .

Comment: what text is being displayed for 1st position of textViewStoreName in your grid view

Comment: If i am getting correct then all json data is being saved in storenamefinal's 0th position. have you tried debugging. i will try once and revert to this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it crashes the application
after debugging i got that the problem is with the image resources 
when i commented below two lines the app works fine.

```
    //check these resources
    Integer x=imagelinks.get(position);
    imageViewStoreImage.setImageResource(x);
```

your showJSON() function that i tried

```
 private void showJSON() {
    try {
        String response ="{\"result\":[{\"storename\":\"Flipkart.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"2\"},{\"storename\":\"Jabong.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"4\"},{\"storename\":\"Myntra.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"5\"},{\"storename\":\"Amazon.in\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"1\"},{\"storename\":\"Snapdeal.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"3\"},{\"storename\":\"Koovs.in\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"6\"},{\"storename\":\"Limeroad.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"7\"},{\"storename\":\"Shopperstop.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"8\"},{\"storename\":\"Stalkbuylove.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"9\"},{\"storename\":\"Yepme.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"10\"},{\"storename\":\"Faballey.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"11\"},{\"storename\":\"Fabindia.com \",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"12\"},{\"storename\":\"PrettySecrets.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"13\"},{\"storename\":\"AmericanSwan.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"14\"},{\"storename\":\"Clovia.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"15\"},{\"storename\":\"Bata.in\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"16\"},{\"storename\":\"TrendyBharat.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"17\"},{\"storename\":\"Royzez.com\",\"imagelinks\":\"\",\"mainpriority\":\"18\"}]} ";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int i=result.length();
        Log.i("Result Length", result.toString());
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            storenamefinal.add(null);
            imagelinksfinal.add(null);
        }
        String temp;
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            JSONObject Data = result.getJSONObject(j);
            Log.i("Data",Data.toString());
            temp= (Data.getString("mainpriority"));
            Log.i("temp", temp.toString());
            storenamefinal.set(Integer.parseInt(temp) - 1, Data.getString("storename"));

            Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
            imagelinksfinal.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        }
        Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,storenamefinal.get(0),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**GridAdapterStores.java file**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by mithilesh.izardar on 6/17/2016.
*/
public class GridAdapterStores extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> storename=new ArrayList<String>();
private  ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks=new ArrayList<Integer>();
public GridAdapterStores(Context c,ArrayList<String> storename,       ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks) {
    context = c;
    this.imagelinks = imagelinks;
    this.storename = storename;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return storename.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View grid;
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_stores,parent,false);
    }
    else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    TextView textViewStoreName = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
    ImageView imageViewStoreImage = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_image);
    textViewStoreName.setText(storename.get(position));
//  Integer x=imagelinks.get(position);
//  imageViewStoreImage.setImageResource(x);
    return grid;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Still it doesn't display anything. I think there is some mistake in mainactivity class. But I am unable to find out. I have implemented this StoresFragment as a fragment for a tab layout which is placed in mainactivity. Do you think I might have done some mistakes anywhere.

Comment: okay, now it works but there is a bug. It only displays when i scroll second time to that tab.

Comment: @Zuqrix the code in your onViewCreated method is the problem i guess.
move all the code from onViewCreated to onCreateView.